# Terminal Tab Title after SSH Session

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh

In Mac OS X (I'm on 10.6.8, though I believe other versions are the same) ssh'ing into a remote machine changes the title of the current tab in Terminal. Annoyingly, when I disconnect from the remote machine, either explicitly with `exit` or via a timeout, the title of the tab doesn't change back to what it was.

On an almost daily basis this nearly causes me to suffer a heart attack, when I'm typing away performing some command or other, only to see out of the corner of my eye that the tab is still named user@remotehost. I'm a cautious user that always tends to `pwd` etc to confirm my location before doing anything, yet it still catches me in a moment of panic when I'm doing `DROP DATABASE x` and I see the remote host name in the tab.

Long story short, is there a way to revert this title when disconnecting from a remote host, or do I have to stick with opening a new tab every time I disconnect, to reset the title?

Comment: terminal names also reset when you quit `npm`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add a `PROMPT_COMMAND` to your  `.bash_profile`

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -ne '\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}\007';$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

The `PROMPT_COMMAND` gets executed every time the prompt is displayed.

Please note that we include the existing `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable, such that we do not lose any existing settings (i.e. `update_terminal_cwd`).

Comment: Be sure to *add* your code to PROMPT_COMMAND rather than replacing it, e.g., `PROMPT_COMMAND="<your code>; $PROMPT_COMMAND"`; otherwise, you’ll disable other functionality that uses this variable. For example, /etc/bashrc uses it to set the terminal’s current working directory so Terminal can display it and use it for various operations.

Comment: @ChrisPage Does the new code need to come before `$PROMPT_COMMAND` for the other functionality to be preserved?

Comment: Why not put it directly into PS1?

Comment: is this how you edit the `.bash_profile`? `sublime $HOME/.bash_profile` ?

Comment: @Awesome_girl Make sure that the `subl` command is installed, and then edit the file from your terminal using `subl ~/.bash_profile`.  If this command doesn't exist, follow this: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html

Answer (score 6):

To make @s01ipsist's solution work with ZSH (new shell on macOS), you can add this to `~/.zshrc`:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -ne '\033]0;${USER}@${HOST}\007';$PROMPT_COMMAND"
precmd() { eval "$PROMPT_COMMAND" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you'll need to paste into your `.bash_profile` file. This is far cleaner and takes the approach what Apple does when it updates your current working directory. The check for the variable `update_term_title` is already present is not really necessary (as nobody calls `bash -- login`), but just present as a guard.

```
if [ -z "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]; then
    # Update the terminal title on every prompt shown
    update_term_title() {
        # Print user@short-hostname once SSH quits.
        echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}\007"
        # Or ${HOSTNAME} if short host names aren't your taste
        # Or echo -ne "\033]0;\007" if you don't want anything.
    }
    # Check to see if update terminal title is present?
    if ! echo $PROMPT_COMMAND | grep -q update_term_title
    then
       # This function is not found in PROMPT_COMMAND, add it
       PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }update_term_title"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Lol, I wondered who wrote this answer... turns out it was me :-)