# How to hide system username also from title of terminal?

Tags: terminal

I know we can use: `PS1="%n@ %1~ %# "` to hide the username within the terminal but I see it on my title too:
[image]

I want to know how can I hide this part as well?

Comment: Does this help?  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/364723/119271

Answer (score 2):

There are two additional places where it could be set:

- If `PROMPT_COMMAND` is set in your shell, unset it
- Check your Terminal settings

  [image]